# iOS application with Postgres DB hosted in AWS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

We need to prototype a cloud connected iOS device application. Through quick research, Amplify seems a good framework for storing offline data and synchronizing to cloud backend. Of course, at backend, we'll need to introduce a layer to synchronize the data from Amplify datastore to Postgres DB hosted at AWS.

Below is AWS' document about jump start of Amplify
https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/ios

Is this approach doable and a good one? Any other good architecture recommended?

Thanks!

Comment: Anything is doable. A good one for what? If i needed to prototype something i'd use SQLite in Swift and some REST framework + Postrgres in AWS.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about REST at the backend. I thought Amplify should have REST support for backend. But it might not have. I'd need to do a bit research.

Comment: @FastLearner, It has REST support. See this: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/ios

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Amplify DataStore to do the need full. DataStore can connect to the remote backend and automatically sync all locally saved data using GraphQL as a data protocol. More details can be found on the following link: [AWS Amplify DataStore - Syncing data to the cloud](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/ios)